Bootstrap with Rails - How do I make Bootstrap styles / classes accessible in Rails app
I have a bare-bones rails app, and I've installed bootstrap according to the steps outlined here:
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass
Adding bootstrap classes to elements on my app/views/layouts/application.html.erb file has no effect. I just want to link this app to bootstrap so that adding bootstrap classes to elements has a visual effect.
I've installed all the gem dependencies according to the instructions linked above.
My app/views/layouts/application.html.erb file has this stylesheet link tag in its header:
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", "data-turbo-track": "reload"%>

And in the app/stylesheets/application.scss file, I have the following import statements:
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";

What am I missing? Any help much appreciated.

The best way to use bootstrap is through cdn, just paste the cdn links in you application.html.erb header.

@AfaqShahidKhan I don't think so. CDN link is dependency of external service. External service could work slowly or even fail

@Jack what rails version do you use? How do you manage your frontend assets (importmap, webpack, esbuild, other)? CSS is about frontend, using gem for that is a dubious decision
